# SSMS: Bit column defaults to Expression when Group By is desired

Tags: ssms, ssms-2014, query-designer, ssms-2005

(Tested in SSMS 2005 & 2014)

When I have a table or view open in **Query and View Designer** and I turn the **Group By** feature on, any bit columns defaults to **Expression**.

Is there any way to change this (by options/settings, registry tweak, or other) to default bit columns to **Group By**?

Thanks for any help anyone can provide,

CTB

Comment: what do you mean by `defaults to expression`?

Comment: @LONG When you turn on the **Group By** feature, a **Group By** column is added to the Grid Pane listing all of the group by/aggregate functions.  Pretty much all data types have **Group By** populated in the **Group By** column by default.  When you add *** (All Columns)**, it defaults to **Count** (I guess **Count_Big** is the only other option for all columns).  But bit columns have the **Expression** option selected by default.  I want to change bit columns to **Group By** by default.